# Two small align images beside a large image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling on how I will code to create a two vertical images and is it possible to lessen the height of the larger image without lessen the width? because I need to fit it on col-md-8 any thoughts about this?

this is the image I need to make.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBXh7.jpg)

HTML and CSS code:

```css
    .img-big{ height: 100%;width: 100%; }
```

```html
    <div class="row col-md-8">
    <img class="row img-big img-responsive" src="/assets/icons/people-crowd-child-kid-large.jpg"></div>
    </div
```

the above code is what I've used to make the bigger image beside image 2 and 3. the dimension of the large image is 900x767

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `flexbox` property to achieve what you want and set the image as background.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  height: 767px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.one {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 50%;
}

.two {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 50%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left image</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="one">First image</div>
    <div class="two">Second image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i have a follow up question? because the image 2 and 3 is not tight as the big image. http://i64.tinypic.com/2u92uu0.png how can i fix this?

Comment: sir i think something is missing because i need to use col-md-8 and col-md-4 for accurate sizes for each images and I'm having a problem about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should format your code like below:

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img class="img-big img-responsive" src="https://en.apkshki.com/storage/5/icon_5dcfce7f86906_5_w256.png"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <img src="https://en.apkshki.com/storage/5/icon_5dcfce7f86906_5_w256.png"></div>
             <img src="https://en.apkshki.com/storage/5/icon_5dcfce7f86906_5_w256.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the two images at the bottom in `col-md-4` if you spread the width `100%` the next image will drop below.

You shouldnt really have a class with both a `row` and a `col-md` in the class name. (See http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

With regards to reducing the height and not the width are you not able to crop the image down on Paint or Photoshop and upload the image with the correct height?

Comment: thanks i will try the code
about the image i think it will not look nice if i will manually reduce the height only.

Comment: @Brain If you want to keep the image high resolution and want to reduce the height you will also have to reduce the width. If you want to just crop out the height the width can stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 5, you can use d-grid gap-x. For example:

**HTML**

```css
.content {
    background-color: transparent;}

     .content .left, .content .right {
    float: left;}

    .full-width-band-hd {
    margin-top: -35px;}

    .txt-yellow {
    color: var(--bs-yellow);}
```

```html
<section class="container-lg">
        <div class="content row">
              <h2 class="txt-yellow full-width-band-hd">Head</h2>
            <!-- Left Side -->
              <h6 class="text-yellow">H6 head</h6>            
              <h3 class="text-yellow">H3 head</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- style in content row will become a class later-->
        <div class="content row" style="height: 642px;">
          <div class="col-md-4 left d-grid gap-3">
            <div class="">
                <img src="image1" width="100%" height="auto" alt="fp1">
              </div>
              <div class="">
                <img src="image2" width="100%" height="auto" alt="fp2">
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End of Left Side -->
          <div class="col-md-8 left">
            <div class="">
              <img src="image3" width="100%" height="auto" alt="fp3">
            </div>

          </div>
        <!-- End of col-md-8 -->

        </div><!-- content row -->
    </section>
```